# Template Toolkit's somevar.substr() and UTF-8

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8, substr, template-toolkit

We use Template Toolkit in a Catalyst app. We configured TT to use UTF-8 and had no problems with it before.

Now I call the substr() method of a string var. Unfortunately it does split the string after *n* bytes instead of *n* chars. If the *n*'th and *(n+1)*'th byte build a unicode char it is split and only the 1st byte is part of substr() result.

**How to fix or workaround that behaviour?**

```
[% string = "fööbär";

string.length; # prints 9

string.substr(0, 5); # prints "föö" (1 ascii + 2x 2 byte unicode)

string.substr(0, 4): # prints "fö?" (1 ascii, 1x 2 byte unicode, 1 unknown char)
%]
```

Until now we had no problems with Unicode chars, neither ones comes from the database nor text in the templates.

**Edit:** This is how I configure the `Catalyst::View::TT` module in my Catalyst app:

```
__PACKAGE__->config(
#   DEBUG => DEBUG_ALL,
    DEFAULT_ENCODING => 'utf-8',
    INCLUDE_PATH => My::App->path_to( 'root', 'templates' ),
    TEMPLATE_EXTENSION => '.tt',
    WRAPPER => "wrapper/default.tt",
    render_die => 1,
);
```

Comment: Does my suggestion (added in an update to my answer) to employ a `use utf8` directive in your source code solve your problem? If not, could you provide some more details that might help people provide a useful answer?

Comment: What do you mean by "2x 2 byte Unicode"?  Unicode is "always" 2-byte (at least).  Otherwise you don't have Unicode text at all -- you have an "encoded" Unicode text stream.  In such cases, you'll need to check the particular encoding method.

Comment: @Stephen: As indicated by the title this is about UTF-8. I would consider UTF-8 a subset of several Unicode encoding. Whatever the exact termini are, I use UTF-8.

Comment: @halo, sorry.  I didn't notice that.

Comment: @Stephen: No, Unicode is most certainly not "always 2-byte at least".  Unicode is zero bytes: it has nothing to do with encoding forms. It is a set of nonnegative integers.

Comment: @Halo, the string length of `"fööbär"` should be 6, not 9. Only as NFD is it 9, but in NFC it should be 6.  You should not ever be dealing with bytes in Perl, only characters.

Answer (score 3):

I did a quick testing with Perl 1.12.2 for MSWin32 Template module.
It could handle all these substr operation properly.

This is my test code:

```
use Template;

# some useful options (see below for full list)
my $config = {
#    DEFAULT_ENCODING => 'utf-8',
    INCLUDE_PATH => 'd:/devel/perl',  # or list ref
    INTERPOLATE  => 1,               # expand "$var" in plain text
    EVAL_PERL    => 1,               # evaluate Perl code blocks
};

# create Template object
my $template = Template->new($config);

# define template variables for replacement
my $vars = {
    var1  => "abcdef"
};

# specify input filename, or file handle, text reference, etc.
my $input = 'ttmyfile.txt';

# process input template, substituting variables
print $template->process($input, $vars);
```

ttmyfile.txt

```
Var = [% var1 %]

[% string = "fööbär" -%]
[% string.length %]   # prints 6
[% string.substr(0, 5) %]  # prints "fööbä"
[% string.substr(0, 4) %]  # prints "fööb"
```

Output:

```
Var = abcdef

6     # prints 6
fööbä  # prints "fööbä"
fööb  # prints "fööb" 
1
```

All works fine, even without `use utf8` nor `DEFAULT_ENCODING`. Key things here:

1. Make sure your template `.tt` files are encoded as UTF8 with [BOM -- `Byte Order Mark`](http://linuxyz.blogspot.com/search/label/i18n). This is a must do task! Because Template-Toolkit is detect the Unicode file encoding according to BOM.

   - You can use Windows Notepad to save a file with BOM, just do `File` --> `Save` --> Encoding: "UTF-8".
   - You can use VIM make it as well by input `set fenc=utf8` and `set bomb`, then save the file, the file will start with BOM.
2. Set the `NCODING` paramter `Template->new({NCODING => 'utf-8'});` as 'utf-8' will enforce `Template` to load template file as 'utf-8'.
3. Suggest to have `use utf8` in your script, it will ensure all your inline strings are encoding as utf8 properly.

Because `Catalyst::View::TT` rely on Template, I believe it should be working as well! Good luck~~~

Comment: Thank you for the example. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me:( I saved the files as UTF8 without BOM and the `fööb` line reads `fö?` and `length` prints 9 instead of 6. Afterwards I saved both files with BOM and length kept 6 but all umlauts turned into question marks. I got the feeling it could be problem with my system. I'll determine this. OS is Fedora 14 KDE Spin. I have no encoding problems anywhere else.

Comment: Good, you have got the right thing! the question marks is caused by your terminal rather than the encoding itself. You can simply redirect the output to a file, and check the file with your editor. It will be right things you want!

Comment: No, UTF-8 is not supposed to have a BOM.

Comment: @tchrist please refer to http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM I think it is really depends on the protocol.

Comment: @halo: perhaps the locale on your computer is set to something other than UTF-8. Execute the `locale` command and see if `UTF-8` appears everywhere.

Comment: +1 @RouMao for writing a useful test case to help the discussion.

Comment: Back after easter holidays: I ran `locale` and everything is set up fine to "en_US.UTF-8", except `LC_ALL` which is set to nothing. I set it to the same value temporarily but it made no difference. Any hints? I have no clue why it doesn't work.

Comment: @halo After you save all your template as UTF-8 with BOM, you can test this web application directly from your browser. It should work properly. :)

Comment: I just realized the document `output.txt` given by `perl test.pl > output.txt` can be opened with my editor (Geany) but is recognized as ISO-8859-1. It cannot be opened when forced to UTF8. Can you confirm that behaviour? I can find how to configure TT's input encoding but not its output encoding. All my *locale*s still set to UTF8.

Comment: @halo could you please paste the output.txt to http://pastebin.com/ So we can check it.

Comment: I found out `Template->new({NCODING => 'utf-8'})` makes TT **read** UTF8 correctly. Thus it can detect string length correctly. With `binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(utf8)";` I can force **output to TTY** be UTF8 and everything is fine than. `use uft8` makes no difference at all. Any hints how to achieve that for output to Catalyst? Here is the pastebin http://pastebin.com/X6xs1rtd with commented examples

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article on UTF-8 provides a table that shows how non-ASCII characters are [encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Design). That table illustrates the following simple rules for UTF-8:

- If the highest bit of a byte is 0, then the byte denotes an ASCII character.
- If the two highest bits of a byte are 11, then this is the start of a multi-byte character, and the number of consecutive 1 bits starting from the highest order bit indicates the total number of bytes in the multi-byte character. Thus, a byte whose bit representation is 110xxxxx is the start of a 2-byte character, 1110xxxx is the start of a 3-byte character, and 11110xxx is the start of a 4-byte character. (You can ignore the hypothetical 5-byte and 6-byte characters because Unicode is limited to being a 21-bit character set rather than a 32-bit character set.)
- If the two highest bits of a byte are 10, then this byte is part of a multi-byte character (but *not* the first byte of that character).

That information should be enough for you to write your own utility functions that are like `string.length` and `string.substring()` but work in terms of characters instead of bytes.

**Update:** The question did not specify the programming language being used, and I was not aware that "Template Toolkit" implied the use of Perl. Once I realised that, I did a Google search and discovered that your problem is likely to be due to the need to add a `use utf8` directive to your source code. You can find a discussion about this [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html).

Comment: Thank you for that. As you can read in the perldoc you linked `use uft8` is only for telling Perl that the *sourcecode itself* is saved in utf8. As the edit shows i already configured `Catalyst::View:TT` to use UTF-8. However, I tried to add `use uft8` to the `Catalyst::View:TT` module and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple (in Perl), fortunately:

```
use Encode qw{encode decode};
```

The way this works is that you decode Unicode strings into Perl strings, whereupon you can use substr() and length() the way you expect, and then you encode them again for output.

With that header:

```
# $unicodeString = 'fööbär';
my $perlString = decode('UTF-8', $unicodeString);
printf "%d\n", length($perlString);  # should be 6
printf "%s\n", substr($perlString, 0, 3);  # should be 'föö'
# whatever other processing you want here with $perlString . . .
# Then, you want to reencode that back to a proper UTF-8 string:
my $unicodeString = encode('UTF-8', $perlString);
```

Would that help?

Comment: I strongly encourage you not to deal with encoded strings at all. Make sure they are decoded ASAP.